# MS Excel vlookup return only single instance

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have A sheet like

```
       A      |       B     |     C   |
1  Customer 1 |  Product 1  |  $150   |
1  Customer 1 |  Product 1  |  ----   |
2  Customer 1 |  Product 2  |  $50    |
3  Customer 2 |  Product 1  |  $150   |
```

The idea is that column C:C pulls the price from a vlookup, but I don't want to add the price if the same ***product*** was already used for this ***customer***, I have this formula that works almost but it eliminates for the same customer even with a different product.  The formula is for column C.

`=IF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-1)="","",IF(COUNTIF($A$3:A3,B3)>1,"",VLOOKUP(C3,data_validation!A:B,2)))`

P.S data_validation is just a different sheet where I create all my validations and I use it to lookup the price based on the product number.

Comment: The question in the title does not represent what you describe : saying that, vlookup is only meant to return one instance.

Comment: I'm not very clear your requirement , if in data_validation sheet 2 products and customers is the same but the $ value is different. Which value do you need?  Do you try the SUMPRODUCT function?

Comment: @Lee data_validation doesn't have the customer info just the products and prices from where the data is pulled down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution incorporating Lee's suggestion to use the SUMPRODUCT() function.
Fill this formula down from C3:

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A$3:A3=A3)*(B$3:B3=B3))>1,"",VLOOKUP(B3,E$4:F$5,2))`

How it works:  The expressions A$3:A3=A3 and B$3:B3=B3 return arrays of True/False values that get longer as the formula is filled down.  For example, in C6, A$3:A6=A6 equals {False;False;False;True} since the last position is the only cell in the range that equals A6.  Similarly, B$3:B6=B6 equals {False;False;True;True} since the last two positions match B6.

Now multiplying these two arrays converts True/False values to 1's and 0's, and performs the equivalent of the logical AND().  The result of the multiplication (in C6) is the array {0;0;0;1}.  SUMPRODUCT() adds up the elements of this array, returning 1.

Now the IF() function returns the result of the VLOOKUP, because the result of SUMPRODUCT() is not > 1.

Looking at the formula in C4, A$3:A4=A4 is {True;True} and B$3:B4=B4 is also {True;True}, so the multiplication gives {1;1}, and SUMPRODUCT() returns 2, and the IF() returns a blank.

EDIT to show results:

[image]

I have placed the lookup table on the same sheet as the data.  You can edit the equation to refer to your lookup table.

Note: if you find this answer helpful, please click the grey checkmark at top left to accept the answer and remove it from the unanswered queue.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Bandersnatch but this adds even if the same customer with different product is selected

Comment: Adds what?  This equation does exactly what you asked for in your question.  It returns the price of the product ONLY for the first instance of a customer/product combination.  See the screenshot in the edited answer.  If you want a different result than this, please explain your requirements more clearly.

Comment: Sorry, you are right it working, but only because I use data validation in the product list, otherwise when I type manually 'Product fake' it will add the value of the last product price. but in my case it works perfect. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: actually I still have a little problem, when I auto populate column C the first empty row returns #N/A and it effects a SUM function I based on that column

Comment: Ok, I think you'll need to wrap the formula in an IFERROR(): `=IFERROR(IF(SUMPRODUCT((A$3:A3=A3)*(B$3:B3=B3))>1,"",VLOOKUP(B3,E$4:F$5,2)),"")`.I haven't checked this formula, but I will in an hour or so when I get back to my computer.

Comment: Yes, that ^ modification will handle the problem.